# csrf(forbidden 403) error in django

Tags: django, csrf

what is problem with the second function of this code? we use the same syntax in the first function and it works correctly,but the second doesn't and we have csrf error...(forbidden 403)

```
from User.models import User_account
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render

def get_info(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['passwd']!=request.POST['cpasswd']:
            return render(request,'signup.html',{'error':'The confirmed password does     not match the first one'})
        new_user = User_account.objects.create(first_name=request.POST['first_name'],last_name=request.POST['last_name'],e_mail=request.POST['e_mail'],passwd=request.POST['passwd'])
    new_user.save()
    return HttpResponse("your account was built")


def signin(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': 'Email or Password is incorrect'})

    user_profile = User_account.objects.filter(e_mail = request.POST['user_email'], passwd = request.POST['password'])     

    if user_profile:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': 'Ecorrect'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': 'Email or Password is incorrect'})
```

Comment: Do you have the csrf tag in the template?

Comment: yes, we have it and use it for the first function and it works!

Comment: Are you sending the form with AJAX?

Comment: no ! ------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Can you share your template? First function returned to signup.html and the second returned to login.html (So to be clear, I guess we need to see what is in them)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def signin(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return  render_to_response('login.html', {'error': 'Email or Password is incorrect'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        user_profile = User_account.objects.filter(e_mail = request.POST['user_email'], passwd = request.POST['password'])     

    if user_profile:
        return render_to_response('login.html', {'error': 'Ecorrect'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response("perfil.html",  {'error': 'Email or Password is incorrect'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: why ? is there anybody who can help me fix it ?